# grails spring security determineTargetUrl not called

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, spring-security, redirect

I implemented my own AuthSuccessHandler to redirect to a controller / action when I need to:

```
class AuthSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        def referer = request.getHeader("Referer")

        println "referer = "+referer

        if(referer?.contains("/some/url/")){
            def id = referer.substring(referer.lastIndexOf("/")+1)      
            println "in ref redirect to "+"/some/other/"+id 
            return "/some/other/"+id
        }
        else{
            println "not in ref redirect to "+super.determineTargetUrl(request, response)
            return super.determineTargetUrl(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

this is in my resources.groovy:

```
authenticationSuccessHandler(AuthSuccessHandler) {
    def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
    requestCache = ref('requestCache')
    defaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
    alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault
    targetUrlParameter = conf.successHandler.targetUrlParameter
    useReferer = conf.successHandler.useReferer
    redirectStrategy = ref('redirectStrategy')
}
```

Everything works like a charm when I login via the url /login/auth. The determineTargetUrl function is called.

But when I go to a protected URL which requires login before the it doesn't after I logged in. The framework simply redirects to the protected URL. I assume that this has to do with that the framework that is saving the URL where I originally wanted to go and redirects to that URL without calling the determineTargetUrl function because it already knows where to go.

I like this feature but anyway I want to have the control about where to redirect because in that special case (when referer contains "/some/url") I want to redirect to another URL.